# How to debug Firefox for Android - Reloads at Image Upload with remote debugger disconnecting

Tags: android, firefox

I got the issue that I want to upload images on the website and when I do this using an html tag with some vue.js sugar on top like

```
<input type="file" ref="file" @change="createImg" accept="image/*" style="display:none"/>
```

I.e. uising display:none as I use a button to programmaticall trigger the input initiation

Upon picking an image e.g. via camera the page reloads. Same code works in Chrome for windows/android/iOS as well was Firefox for Windows, Edge for windows/Android and Safari for iOS so is FF for Android specific.

I tried remote debuggin but once I get to selecting images it just tells me Error: Debug target was disconnected.  So I am blind and cannot debug.

So I wonder:

- how can i debug this
- is this known behavior and is there maybe a solution out there?

Update: I found that this only occurs when using the camera but not selecting files but the disconnect of the remote debug tools still occurs and I have no solution to it - and ist must be Android FF specific as it works in the other cases

Comment: Exact same issue. Please post if you found an answer or alternate solution.